# Where are my addons?

Tags: add-on

Where can I get the add-ons for Blender 2.76?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15356/1853

Comment: If you are a new blender user, see the link that @cegaton posted to find answers to many common topics for new users.  Anyway, it is better if you can elaborate a bit more your question, to get a proper answer or even some better advice: are you saying that you know where they should be but they aren't there (anymore?), in you local install, or you don't know at all where you can find them?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why I did not have any add-on files. After I downloaded Blender onto my hard drive I unzipped it in the Download folder because it would not unzip in my C/Program Files for some reason. But I figured out that I can just name a new folder in the C/Program Files and drag the unzipped folder from the Downloads folder, and now it's fine. I hope this answer is helpful to others.

Comment: This won't have happened if you'd have already known this tip: http://www.blendernation.com/2015/07/25/restoring-custom-defaults-quick-tip/